# Is It possible to access photo editing extension from my app

Tags: ios, ios8, photo-gallery

I am making an iOS app for photos and stores photos locally inside my app. I have to edit some photos. So, I have to write a lot of code to do exactly like apple photos app does. Instead of writing the code myself is there any possible way to access iPhone photos app, just for editing from my app. And is it possible to use extensions to access photos editing features? Thanks In advance!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I don't exactly what do you mean by extension but you can access the photo library using UIImagePickerController (Here's the class reference https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/ and the sample code https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html). And you can allow editing like follows

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
     [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
} else {
    [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
}

[imagePicker setAllowsEditing:YES];
[imagePicker setDelegate:self];
```

Comment: extensions mean app extensions. And You might heard of iOS allows use of third party keyboards. those are using extensions. https://developer.apple.com/app-extensions/

Comment: Ah, the app extensions thingie. Sadly from my personal experience, you can trigger some actions like opening the picker view and stuff. But the whole edit functionalities you have to implement it yourself.

Comment: so what you are saying is i can't use another apps extensions for Photo editing.

Comment: Apparently no. You have to implement it yourself.